# Error when instantiating ADODB ConnectionPtr on Windows Server 2008

Tags: c++, windows-server-2008, windows-7-x64, adodb

I have an application that I have compiled on Windows 7 64-bit. It works fine on that PC, but I am now trying to get it to work on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.

Whenever I try and instantiate ADODB::Connection, I receive the following error:

```
HRESULT : No such interface supported; hr=0x80004002
```

Code that generates the error is below:

```
CoInitialize(NULL);
_ConnectionPtr link;
link.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Connection) );
if (link == NULL) {
    _com_error err(hr);
    Error(err);
}
```

Now I found this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/12c95ba7-60ed-4303-b4da-e811150b8d13/cannot-able-to-instance-adodbconnection-in-2008-r2-server-core-no-such-interface-supported?forum=vcgeneral, which seems to suggest the problem with a particular windows update, and provides a fix for it. However, the update that supposedly causes the problems is not on this machine, and if I try to install the fix I simply get an error saying that the update "does not apply to this computer".

Any ideas anyone? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to update your Win7 machine, not the target machine.

Comment: Thanks; okay I've tried that and still no luck. The install just said the hotfix was already installed on the Win7 machine.

Comment: No one else has any ideas?

Comment: I ran into the exact same problem. I haven't tested the KB patch but I confirm that building the program on an old XP VM (which I use as a non-automated build machine) addressed the problem.

Comment: This sounds similar to a problem I had with compiling with Visual Studio on a Windows 7 PC and the resulting application not working with SQL Server correctly when put on a Windows XP machine. "See Microsoft KB article 2517589 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2517589" and for VS 2013 "Rather than the work around for Visual Studio 2005 using msado28.dll you instead need to use msado60.tlb which appears to have the class ids corrected."